# Should I store transformation matrices separately?

Tags: android, opengl-es, transform, opengl-es-2.0

I am new to OpenGL ES 2.0, and I'm trying some 2-D rendering.

Suppose each object would be translated, rotated, skewed and scaled, and can be selected upon a mouse click, I now have two choices:

Store a matrix for each of the transformation, and pass them separately to the vertex shader.  The matrix multiplication would be done on the GPU, which I suppose would be faster.  It's also convenient when only one of the transformation matrix is changed.  Deciding the selection is somehow heavy because I'll need to apply each of the matrices to a vector.

Store only one matrix as the product of all the transformation matrices and pass it to the vertex shader.  It might be good because some methods such as `Matrix.scaleM()` and `Matrix.translateM()` are fast and do not require a multiplication.  It's also because the uniform data we upload to the shader every frame is reduced.  But every time one of the transformation matrices is changed, the whole product should be recalculated.  Deciding the selection is relatively simple because I need only to apply a single matrix to a vector.

Any suggestion on the choice is welcomed.

Comment: Do you have the code to calculate the matrix transformation written in the vertex shader?

Comment: @Radu It's simply some multiplications, such as `gl_Position = uTrans * uRotate * uScale * aPos;`.

Comment: Well you see - on CPU you'll need to do matrix multiplication only once per object. On GPU you'll need to do matrix multiplication per every vertex of object (thousand of times). So it is not necessary faster this way.

Comment: @peter, you'd really have to benchmark if performance is your main concern, because it depends on both processing power (GPU is faster than CPU), upload bandwidth (uploading more matrices may negate any performance boost you get from the GPU) and actual number of objects (again, having to do the calculation for lots of objects may negate any performance boost you get from the GPU).

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko I see.  But what if the multiplication on the GPU is much faster?  I am not sure about this.

Comment: See - let's assume cost of multiplying those three matrices on CPU is A. And cost of multiplying those three matrices on GPU is B. So if you have N vertices, then doing matrix multiplication on CPU will be more faster if A < N * B (simply speaking). So you must measure and see what is faster if you don't know exact numbers for A and B.

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko I agree.  That's where some benchmark is needed.

Comment: you could use a math program to pre-multiply all the matrices into one composite matrix. Microsoft Mathematics allows you to supply matrices full of unknown variables and get the resulting composite matrix. Once you have that, you can just flag the matrix as dirty any time skew/scale/ect is changed, and recalculate the one composite matrix. Whether you do that one computation on gpu or cpu is up to you, but eliminating all the matrix multiplication should definitely improve your situation.

Comment: @Nick Thanks.  And since I am doing something 2D, it would be easier to eliminate the multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if a benchmark is performed, because the performance is related to multiple concerns:

The gap between the multiplication performance of CPU and GPU.

Upload bandwidth for uniforms.

The number of vertices applied with the transformation.

The possibility of marking only one of the transformation matrices as dirty.

The frequency of changing the transformation parameters.

It's typically okay to do this locally because the matrix multiplication could be optimized easily when concerning only 2D objects.